# Assign an operator to a variable in Scala

Tags: scala, operators

Given this spinet of code in Scala:

```
val mapMerge : (Map[VertexId, Factor], Map[VertexId, Factor]) => Map[VertexId, Factor] = (d1, d2) => d1 ++ d2
```

That can be shortened to:

```
val mapMerge : (Map[VertexId, Factor], Map[VertexId, Factor]) => Map[VertexId, Factor] = _ ++ _
```

What actually the code does is renaming the operator ++ of Map[VertexId, Factor] and therefore: Is there a way to assign that operator to the variable? Like in this imaginary example:

```
val mapMerge : (Map[VertexId, Factor], Map[VertexId, Factor]) => Map[VertexId, Factor] = Map.++
```

And probably with type inference it would enough to write

```
val mapMerge = Map[VertexId,Factor].++
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, because the "operators" in Scala are *instance* methods — not functions from a typeclass, like in Haskell.
Whey you write `_ ++ _`, you are creating a new 2-argument function(lambda) with unnamed parameters. This is equivalent to `(a, b) => a ++ b`, which is in turn equivalent to `(a, b) => a.++(b)`, but not to `(a, b) => SomeClass.++(a, b)`.

You can emulate typeclasses by using implicit arguments (see ["typeclasses in scala" presentation](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1_k9EVuY0Yrv4cESiYC1IKvnMSaZ-gJYFy2P0R_DI4Ew/edit?pli=1#slide=id.i0))

You can pass "operators" like functions — which are not really operators. And you can have operators which look the same. See [this example](http://ideone.com/TvrCBM):

```
object Main {

    trait Concat[A] { def ++ (x: A, y: A): A }
    implicit object IntConcat extends Concat[Int] {
        override def ++ (x: Int, y: Int): Int = (x.toString + y.toString).toInt
    }

    implicit class ConcatOperators[A: Concat](x: A) {
        def ++ (y: A) = implicitly[Concat[A]].++(x, y)
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val a = 1234
        val b = 765

        val c = a ++ b // Instance method from ConcatOperators — can be used with infix notation like other built-in "operators"

        println(c)

        val d = highOrderTest(a, b)(IntConcat.++) // 2-argument method from the typeclass instance

        println(d)
        // both calls to println print "1234765"
    }

    def highOrderTest[A](x: A, y: A)(fun: (A, A) => A) = fun(x, y)

}
```

Here we define Concat typeclass and create an implementation for Int and we use operator-like name for the method in typeclass.

Because you can implement a typeclass for any type, you can use such trick with any type — but that would require writing quite some supporting code, and sometimes it is not worth the result.